# How to append text to a file in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a form in my app that the user fills out, then the app needs to write what the user entered into a .java file that is then sent to the user. Basically, I'm making a mobile Java IDE. Please help! I need to know how to append text into certain locations in the file. Excuse me if this doesn't make sense, just ask me what part is confusing, I might be able to explain it better.

Comment: You can use placeholders in your file at those location and then replace it with the text you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably a lot better off storing all your text in a database, where you can easily insert new text at any location.

Actually storing the text in a file is problematic - appending is easy, you just open the file, seek to the end, and then write new text.  But you really want arbitrary insertion of text which means seeking to that point in the file, reading in the rest of the file, writing out your new data, then writing out the old remainder of the file...

If you store all the text in a database you can organize it to make it easy to insert new text, probably append some useful metadata about the text, and when the user asks to email the file simply write everything you have out to a file in temporary storage and send that (or create the text in memory and send it as NSData).